# Is it possible to edit properties of content control box in a Word doc embedded inside an Excel sheet?

Tags: excel, ms-word

I have a Word 2010 document embedded inside an Excel sheet. I want to create content control boxes inside the word doc which can be populated programatically.  For this I need to set tags for the content control.

I read on the [MSDN website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg605189(v=office.14).aspx) and some other sources that it is simple enough - you just have to enable Design Mode and then right click the content control box and click Properties. However, the properties option is grayed out and disabled even though I'm in Design Mode.

When I do this on a standalone Word document (not an embedded one), it works just fine. So that's a workaround I'm using right now. However it's really inconvenient to have to create the boxes in the standalone Word doc and copy them over into the one embedded in Excel.

Is it possible to edit properties of content control box in a Word doc embedded inside an Excel sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done programmatically, something like the code snippet that follows.

An embedded Word document is an Excel OLEObject; such an object can be named, for example: ws.Objects(1).Name = "WordDoc" - this is saved in the workbook and will remain the same, even if other objects are added later. This does not name the document, only the object on the surface of the Worksheet.

If the embedded document has never been accessed during a session, it first needs to be activated. As doing so causes the screen to jump and the selection to change, IF conditions are included to test that and first activate the OLEObject, as well as re-selecting the cell that was active previously.

Working with the .Tag property is shown in the For Each...Next loop. You can see the result if you go into Design Mode.

Note that the macro will not work if you're in Design Mode or if the selection is in the embedded Word document.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim currCel As Excel.Range
    Dim oDoc As OLEObject

    Set currCel = Application.Selection
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    'Debug.Print ws.OLEObjects.Count
    Set oDoc = ws.OLEObjects("WordDoc")
   ' Debug.Print oDoc.OLEType 'Type 1 = Embedded
    WorkWithWordDoc oDoc, currCel
End Sub

Sub WorkWithWordDoc(oDoc As OLEObject, selRange As Excel.Range)
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim wasActivated As Boolean
    Dim cc As Word.ContentControl

    'On first opening the Workbook
    'the OLE interface of the OLEObject
    'isn't accessible, so activate it
    wasActivated = True
    On Error Resume Next
    Set doc = oDoc.Object
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        Excel.Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        oDoc.Activate
        wasActivated = False
        Set doc = oDoc.Object
       Excel.Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    For Each cc In doc.ContentControls
        cc.Tag = "CC in embedded Doc"
    Next

    'Clean up
    If Not wasActivated Then
        'Deactivate the document
        selRange.Select
    End If
    Set doc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Not within Excel, no. Right-click it and choose "Document object/open" and it will open in Word. But you said you didn't want to open it in Word. And if you don't want a code solution then you shouldn't be asking on StackOverfow. This is an end-user question, in that case.

Comment: Which StackExchange site should I ask this question on, if not SO?

Comment: Yeah I got that. Was asking for the next time I have a question of this kind. Thanks!